# Trying to use koa bodyparser and ctx.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I'm trying to learn koa and can't figure out why i'm getting the error:

```
server error TypeError: ctx.body is not a function
    at getHandler (/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/learn-koa/server.js:32:7)
```

when I run this code:

```js
'use strict'

const Router = require('koa-router')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')

function server (app) {
  const router = new Router()
  router.get('/foo', getHandler)
  app.use(bodyParser())
  app.use(router.routes())


  app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      await next();
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.status = err.status || 500;
      ctx.body = err.message;
      ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
    }
  });

  app.on('error', (err, ctx) => {
    console.log('server error', err, ctx)
  });

  app.listen(4000)
}

function getHandler (ctx, next) {
  // ctx.set('Location', 'http://localhost:3000/foo')
  ctx.body({ foo: 'bar' })
}

module.exports = server
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly what the issue says it is: `ctx.body is not a function`

From the docs:

> A Koa Response object is an abstraction on top of node's vanilla response object

```
Response aliases

The following accessors and alias Response equivalents:

    ctx.body
    ctx.body=
```

So essentially `ctx.body` is an object to which you assign something to be sent as response.

If you look at the `Hello World` example, the response is just assigned to the `Response` object which then `koa` sends.

```
app.use(async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

So, changing your code to following serves the response body as `json`

```
function getHandler (ctx, next) {
  // ctx.set('Location', 'http://localhost:3000/foo')
  ctx.body = { foo: 'bar' };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aware that GET request don't have a body, only POST request do?

Comment: But they can still return a JSON resopnse, which is my understanding of what `ctx.body` is doing, no?

Answer (score 1):

From [`koajs/bodyparser`](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) docs

`ctx.body` doesn't exist, and it's `ctx.request.body` returning the JSON object (not a function)